# How to create CAdES-T signature via Chilkat Crypt2 object

Tags: c#, sign, chilkat

Is it possible to create CAdES-T digital signatures via the Chilkat Crypt2 object?.
I have read documentation and i found only how to sign in basic CAdES format but i need extend it with a timestamp (CAdES-T).
If the answers are negatives, any alternative?
I'm using Chilkat v9.5.0.0 for .NET and C# language.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sample file already signed using CAdES-T, please send it to Matt (support@chilkatsoft.com) and we'll see what we can do...

Comment: thank you Matt but i need to sign a string in CAdES-T (not a file in this case)